# jquery ajax request is Forbidden in IE. How to fix (any workaround)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("select#oblast").change(function () {
                var oblast_id = $("#oblast > option:selected").attr("value");
                $("#Rayondiv").hide();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "http://site.com/Regions.aspx/FindGorodByOblastID/",
                    data: 'oblast_id=' + oblast_id,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {                       
                        if (data.length > 0) {

                            var options = '';
                            for (p in data) {
                                var gorod = data[p];
                                options += "<option value='" + gorod.Id + "'>" + gorod.Name + "</option>";
                            }
                            $("#gorod").removeAttr('disabled').html(options);

                        } else {

                            $("#gorod").attr('disabled', false).html('');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I downvoted because no attempt was made to provide meaningful extra information in the question. Pasting a large body of code and asking "what's wrong?" isn't all that good.

Comment: @1gn1ter *Are* you running this on the same domain you're making the request to? You say it's "forbidden", what error message are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to call a URL on a third-party site you will need to look in to JSONP (JSON with Padding) options. These are designed to make it slightly easier to work with third-party services.

See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and the discussion of the "jsonp" in there for some additional details.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this code running? Unless you're on `http://site.com/`, that won't work for security reasons.

If that's the case, is there any way you make the request and do whatever server side?

Maybe make the request to some page you set up on your site, and in its code behind do the work:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
String html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
```

Comment: Yeah the domain you're running in is key here - IE won't allow cross-domain GETs as far as I know